# Change path's in yaml files

Tags: python, regex

Hello python and regex experts!

I have a file tree with a lot of yaml files where I need to change a path string several places in the files.

A yaml file could look like:

#### BEFORE

```
- !import ../../../app/app.yml
- !import ../../fw/fw/app.yml
- !import ../../id/id/app.yml

includes:    [ ../, ../../../app/include/, ../../fw/include, ]

includes:
    - ../
    - ../../../app/include/
    - ../../fw/include
```

and needs to be changed to:

#### WANTED

```
- !import ../../../Sys/app/app.yml
- !import ../../Sys/fw/fw/app.yml
- !import ../../id/id/app.yml

includes:    [ ../, ../../../Sys/app/include/, ../../Sys/fw/include, ]

includes:
    - ../
    - ../../../Sys/app/include/
    - ../../Sys/fw/include
```

... So every path has to be prefixed with /Sys, as the location of the files pointed to has changed. Note that some paths must not be changed: '- !import ../../id/id/app.yml' must not be changed (+ possibly other paths as well)

There are two include tags in the example above, as it differs how this is written in the files to be changed.

So I need a regex that work for alle combinations above.  I have tried a lot of iterations but I am struggeling to cover both include tags.

Note: I will rather use a plain text file parsing rather than using pyaml in order not to destroy the format of the files as some of them contains a lot of comments.

Any suggestions are welcome - Thank you

Comment: "(+ possibly other paths as well)" is a scary thought. The resulting expression might work for what you have there, but it surely won't accommodate unknowns. I'd suggest you perform multiple replaces, replacing exactly what you want replaced (e.g. one for `../app` with `../Sys/app`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use something like this:

```
output = re.sub(r"\.\./(?=\w)(?!id)", "../Sys/", input)
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/bJ6oX3)

Note that with limited information on what should not be changed, it's hard to come up with one that will properly not replace some of your file paths. Regex work on patterns, so without an appropriate rule, you're bound to find shortcomings.

Comment: Hi Jerry. Thanks for your input. I was thinking of making an exclude list of what not to change. Can I use a list and exchange the 'id' in (?!id) when running through the list?

Comment: @PeterDalgaardHansen If you have a list of things to exclude, sure. You can use something like `r"\.\./(?=\w)(?!" + strList + ")"` where `strList = "|".join(list)` so that you don't have to loop through the list of words. Hm, by the way, I also just realised something. Do you have file names with non-alphanumeric characters? If no, it might be a good idea to use `r"\.\./(?=\w)(?!(?:" + strList + ")\b)"` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
input = re.sub("((?:\.\./)+)(?=[a-zA-Z0-9])", '\\1Sys/', input)
```

Capturing the consecutive `../` and if it is followed by an alphanumeric, then capture it in group `\\1`

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

pat = re.compile(r"""
((\.\./){2,}) # at least two levels up
(?!id/)       # no replace of id/ paths
(.*?)
""", flags=re.VERBOSE)

print pat.sub(r"\1Sys/\3", yaml)
```

Output:

```
- !import ../../../Sys/app/app.yml
- !import ../../Sys/fw/fw/app.yml
- !import ../../id/id/app.yml

includes:    [ ../, ../../../Sys/app/include/, ../../Sys/fw/include, ]

includes:
    - ../
    - ../../../Sys/app/include/
    - ../../Sys/fw/include
```